# How to add xsd in WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

My requirement is to create a webservice on WebSphear. I want to add my xsd file into WSDL. For that I've written my xsd file below -

```
<xsd:element name="getAppDate" ></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="getAppDateResponce"></xsd:element>

   <xsd:complexType name="getAppDate">
  <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="appdate" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="uuName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="getAppDateResponce">
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="return" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:schema>
```

Now I've written one interface for JAX-WS below -

```
 public interface BookAppointment {

String getAppDate(String date,String uuname);
boolean getAppDateResponce(String date,String uuname);
       }
```

Next step: I'm executing Java2WSDL command to generate wsdl -

```
   java org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL -o ..\appointmentbooking.wsdl -C C:\Users\px00395
   \IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\PeoplesoftWS\bin\servicecenter.xsd -l 
    http://localhost:9081/AxisServlet/services/appointmentbook  
    com.ubs.peoplesoft.BookAppointment
```

But I'm getting message : 
The  has already been specified as, C:\Users\px00395\IBM\rati
onalsdp\workspace\PeoplesoftWS\bin\servicecenter.xsd.  It cannot be specified again as com.ubs.peoplesoft.BookAppointment. Please let me know what wrong I'm doing here and how can I add xsd into WSDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may **include** your schema to wsdl, something like

```
<include schemaLocation="C:\Users\px00395
   \IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\PeoplesoftWS\bin\servicecenter.xsd" />
```

Or you may **import** schema, something like this:

```
<import namespace="mynamespace"
        schemaLocation="C:\Users\px00395
   \IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\PeoplesoftWS\bin\servicecenter.xsd" />
```

If you work in a team, you'd better use some local sever to host your schemas, rather than local file system. This way you won't have to synchronize and copy the .xsd to all develoeprs' computers.

---

Please, reference WSDL 2.0 specification for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi Alex, Do I need to manually write this inside wsdl? If I execute the above java2wsdl with argument -C <schema location>, then will not be able to import automatically?

Comment: Depends on your IDE, it may let you do this. But independent of your IDE you can always add it manually.